# How to pass the product color information to the checkout in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Please I need help on passing the product color attribute to the checkout page for a project I am working on.
I am working with Laravel 9 and Livewire.

I have been able to display the product colors from the DB information in the product details page, but I have no clue on how to pass the selected product color when the product is added to cart to the checkout page for order confirmation.

This is what the product details looks like

**product-details.blade.php**

```
<h2>{{ $product->name }}</h2>
<div class="price-box pt-20">
    <span class="new-price new-price-2">&#8358;
        <span class="text-danger">
            {{ number_format((float) $product->price, 2) }}
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="">
    <span class="new-price">
        <p>
            <span class="float-left">
                <label for="color"> Select Colour: </label>
            </span>
            <select class="nice-select" name="color">
                @foreach ($colors as $color)
                    <option value="{{ $color }}">{{ $color }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </p>
    </span>
    <br>
</div>
<br>
<div style="margin-bottom: 50px;"></div>
<div class="product-desc">
    <p>
        <span>{!! $product->description !!}</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**checkout.blade.php**

```
@if ($cart_count>0)
<div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
    <div class="your-order">
        <h3>Your order details</h3>
        <div class="your-order-table table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="cart-product-name">Product</th>
                        <th class="cart-product-total">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach(\Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::content() as $product)
                    <tr class="cart_item">
                        <td class="cart-product-name">
                            {{ $product->name }} | {{ $product->colour }}
                            <strong class="product-quantity"> × {{$product->qty}}</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart-product-total">
                            <span class="amount">&#8358;{{$product->price}}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
                        <th>Cart Subtotal</th>
                        <td>
                            <span class="amount">&#8358; {{ $subtotal }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
                        <th>Cart Tax</th>
                        <td>
                            <span class="amount">&#8358; {{ $tax }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="order-total">
                        <th>Order Total</th>
                        <td>
                            <strong>
                                <span class="amount">&#8358; {{ $total }}</span>
                            </strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, I am using Gloudemans Shoppingcart.
This is what my product details livewire component looks like

**ProductDetails.php**

```
class ProductDetails extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    public $productid, $category, $colors, $sizes;
    public $product, $quantity, $productquantity;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product-details', [
            'productfromcats'=> Product::where('category', '=', $this->category)
                ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC')
                ->paginate(8, ['*'], 'catsPage'),
        ]);
    }

    public function mount($product_id)
    {
        $this->product = Product::where('product_id', '=', $product_id)->get()->first();
        $this->colors = $this->product->colour;
        $this->sizes = $this->product->size;
        $search = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) use ($product_id) {
            return $cartItem->id === $product_id;
        });
        if ($search->count() > 0) {
            $cartproduct = $search->first();
            $this->productquantity = $cartproduct->qty;
        } else {
            $this->productquantity = 0;
        }
    }

    public function addItemToCart($item, $qty)
    { 
        $cartItem = Cart::add(
            [
                'id' => $item['id'],
                'name' => $item['name'],
                'qty' => $qty,
                'price' => $item['price'],
                'weight' => 0,
                'options' => [
                    'size' => $item['size'],
                    'colour' => $item['colour'],
                    'images' => $item['images']
                ]
            ]
        );
        $cartItem->associate('\App\Models\Product');
        $this->productquantity = Cart::get($cartItem->rowId)->qty;
        if (Cart::get($cartItem->rowId)->qty == 0) {
            Cart::remove($cartItem->rowId);
        }
        $this->emit('cart_updated');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the colour of the product directly.

```
<td class="cart-product-name">
    {{ $product->name }} | {{ $product->colour }}
    <strong class="product-quantity"> × {{ $product->qty }}</strong>
</td>
```

Instead access the colour using the `options` as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#example)

```
{{
    $product->options->has('colour')
    ? is_array($product->options->colour)
        ? ' | ' . implode(", ", $product->options->colour)
        : ' | ' . $product->options->colour
    : ''
}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @linktoahref for your answer, but I get an error message in the **checkout.blade.php** saying `Array to string conversion`.

Comment: @Chizo can you share the output of `dump($product->options)` in your blade file

Comment: Here is the output @linktoahref - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SVyWTIUOtUiJj7E9pJW90R0WZfKMPMQn?usp=drive_link

Comment: I appreciate your assistance @linktoahref, it now displays the colors in the database. However, I actually wish to display the selected color from the details page, that is **product-details.blade.php**

Comment: @Chizo Won't `\Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::content()` show the contents of the product in the cart ? You can use the same function in the `product-details.blade.php` to show the colours of the items in the cart.